# How to add a fragment to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I am android beginner and have couple of things which I wanted to know.

- how to make a fragment to be shown at the bottom of the screen when clicked one of the markers as shown in this gif:

[image]

- how to achieve this functionality, When dragging up the text it should show complete  fragment
- how can I style the text view in the fragment, where I wanted to show the "Address" and vertical ruler and a Distance in metrics at the right corner of the screen as shown on the gif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your looking for is [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

you can set its anchor, you can hide it, you can customize the view that is being used by it. Its easy I tried this library and its awesome.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can we achieve this functionality using frames and framelayout ?

Comment: SlidingUpPanel is your best choice, you have the ability to define 2 different layouts (one for the panel, and another for the main screen). It is quick to use, and can be implemented in a few minutes

Comment: @harvey_slash I was just wondering whether we can do it from scratch which helps me to understand how to design such complex layouts, if no one answers it , I will accept this answer.

Comment: @user1430462 if you asked me , I rather not 'reinvent-the-wheel'. here is the [src of SlidingUpPanel.java](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java) , you can learn from it by reading and testing the code. And also you can pull a request you can send it over. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewPager for Screen Slides. This will help: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not need a page slider, I have to show a fragment on top of another fragment.